# Inverting this particular Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

Using Powershell, I have this string that needs parsing :

```
,,Server.domain.abc.com,I1234
```

I'm trying to return only the part after the last "," character (here : I1234)

I sucessfully found how to isolate it using :

```
[^,]+$
```

https://regexr.com/471q7

but how do i invert this match so I can REPLACE all that is NOT this part with nothing.

My goal is to be able to do :

```
$var -replace "XXXX"
```

and end up with only that last part.

Comment: `$var -replace '.*,'`

Comment: Very great, thanks. Sorry for the duplicate I tried searching stack before asking.